# numpy.linalg.eigh works with numpy array from sym.lambdify() but not from np.array()

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, lambdify

Here's the code.  2a works but 2b does not, even though both matrices have the same shape and the same type.  Can anybody explain?

```
import sympy as sym  
import numpy as np

x1, x2 = sym.symbols('x1 x2')  
f = 2*x1**2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2**2 + 2*x1 - 2*x2  
xk = np.array([[0 , 1]])  
print("xk shape = ", xk.shape)  
fmat = sym.Matrix([f])  
H = sym.hessian(fmat, (x1, x2))  
print("Symbolic H")  
sym.pprint(H)  

# 2a: Convert the SymPy Matrix to Numpy array using lambdify and then substitute values  
Hnp = sym.lambdify((x1, x2), H, 'numpy')  
Hknp = Hnp(xk[0][0], xk[0][1])  
print("Hknp")  
sym.pprint(Hknp)  
print("Hknp type:", type(Hknp))  
print("Hknp shape = ", Hknp.shape)  
v, Q = np.linalg.eigh(Hknp)  
print("v:", v)  
print("Q:")  
sym.pprint(Q)  

# 2b: Substitute values into SymPy Matrix then convert to Numpy array  
Hks = H.subs([(x1, xk[0][0]), (x2, xk[0][1])])  
Hk = np.array(Hks)  
print("Hk")  
sym.pprint(Hk)  
print("Hk type:", type(Hk))  
print("Hk shape = ", Hk.shape)  
v, Q = np.linalg.eigh(Hk)  
print("v:", v)  
print("Q:")  
sym.pprint(Q)
```

Comment: What do mean by 'does not'? You should show the error!  Show the prints as well.  Not everyone can run your code to see these things for themselves.

Comment: Naively passing `sympy` expressions to `numpy/scipy` often gives problems.  You have to examine the resulting array carefully before proceeding.  `lambdify` is the safeist interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> Hk
array([[4, -2],
       [-2, 2]], dtype=object)


>>> Hknp.dtype
dtype('int64')
```

The solution is `Hk = np.array(Hks, dtype=np.int64)`.

Comment: Very useful to know now that dtype is important.  In this case using float would be best.  If the matrix calculation happens to result in a float but I declare the dtype as int64, Python (as one would expect) truncates to an integer.